How to redirect the standard output to file without buffering?
I have a Python script test.py, which writes 100 lines, one per second:
from time import sleep

for i in range(100):
  print(f'line {i}')
  sleep(1)

I would like to redirect its output to log.txt file without buffering, i.e. each second a line is appended to the file.
I tried:
python3 test.py > log.txt
python3 test.py | tee log.txt
stdbuf -oL python3 test.py > log.txt
script -c "python3 test.py" log.tx

None of these options writes to log.txt line by line while test.py is running. The whole output is dumped at program completion or interruption. What is the solution?

The program itself must be changed to not buffer – or to flush the buffered data more often.

Run python with the -u option,
or use sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True),
or call print(..., flush=True),
or call sys.stdout.flush() after every print.

When stdbuf -oL is used, it injects code that reconfigures Glibc 'stdout' in a similar manner, but it only affects Glibc FILE* buffering (i.e. from C code) but not the Python equivalent.

Thank you, it works. I'm curious why the output going to the terminal is not buffered, i.e. program displays one line per second, but the redirected output is.

Python, similar to libc for C code, uses isatty() to check for terminal and decide between default buffering policies. Output to a terminal is not buffered – or more accurately line-buffered, i.e. flushed when a \n is output – because the terminal is usually meant to be seen interactively, while output to a non-tty more commonly is not, with "tail -f out.txt" being exception not the rule. (Although that being said, stderr output is line-buffered by default in modern Python versions, as it traditionally is in C stdio, so that error messages would be "immediate" even if going to a non-tty.)

Thank you. Is there a bash command to direct the output both to file and terminal at the same time?

A single file descriptor can only be redirected to one place at a time, but you can pipe the output to tee to duplicate it, e.g. python foo.py | tee out.txt. (Keep in mind that tee itself has standard buffering, so if you want to pipe it further, then python | stdbuf -oL tee | grep_or_whatever might be necessary.)
